# DbContext.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync throws exception if database already exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm new to Entity Framework and am trying to set up code to initialize an SQL Server LocalDB database, if it doesn't already exist.

To do that, I'm using the DbContext.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync() method, which according to the documentation, will set up the database if it doesn't already exist, or do nothing if the database already exists.

The first time I call this method, the database is created and things are good. The second time I call this method, I am greeted with the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Database 'MyDatabase' already exists. Choose a different database name.'

I am trying to understand why this exception is thrown, when the documentation says that the EnsureCreatedAsync method won't do anything, if the database already exists.

The DbContext.Database class doesn't seem to provide any methods for checking if the database already exists, so I can't just bypass the EnsureCreatedAsync method myself.

The code I'm trying to use, looks like this:

```
DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext> optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;AttachDbFileName=MyDatabase.mdf");

MyContext context = new MyContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
```

Comment: Looks like EF Core still has issues with `AttachDbFileName` in connection string under some circumstances. The simplest is to omit that parameter if possible.

Comment: Ivan Stoev, you are correct. Removing the AttachDbFilename alone didn't get rid of the problem, but removing it and deleting the previously created database, will create the new database in the current user's directory and the problem will disappear. If you submit your comment as an answer, I will accept that answer as being the correct solution.

Comment: I've run into an issue with tests running in parallel that are all calling `EnsureCreated()`, it seems it's not thread-safe and if two are run at once they both try to create the database.